# How do I format the bibliography to a specific order?

Tags: biblatex

I need that the biography to have this specific order and format:

Author surname in all-caps and first name initials followed by a point, the document's title in italic, the editor, country, pages cited, number of volume, year.

Example:

> DAL ZOTTO P., LARRE J.M., MERLET A., PICAU L., *Memotech Génie énergétique*, Editor Casteilla, France, pages 153 to 159, 2014.

Currently I'm using `biblatex`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable teX code you have tried so far and do not forget to add the used bib entry. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 1):

This is my first time answering a question here, so bear with me please in case my answer is not the best. Also you did not post any snippets with your question, so it makes answering a bit harder. Also, you did not mention how the citation should look in the text itself, which makes it a bit harder to know whether you will be able to use my suggestion, but here goes a possible solution:

1. Books do not have an address field. Since solutions to change
   that are more intricate, I find that simply inserting it in the
   Publisher field is easier. Reference to properties available for the
   book type: https://www.bibtex.com/e/book-entry/ . I Also did that to the pages field, since it is usually printed at the end.

**===== EDIT =====**

As mentioned by [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) below, the property Location can be given to a @book entry type, and address, if used, remaps to location. In any case I tried using the address field during testing and still could not properly get it to fit your description of bibliography style, so maybe the solution I gave is still the least worse one.

**===============**

With those constraints in mind and the example you gave, I find that the style "apa" is the closest one to meet these requirements. In this style, the last author is preceded by "and" but this post over here had a great discussion on how to deal with this:

[Biblatex: Remove 'and' before last author BUT leave it if there are only two authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636780/biblatex-remove-and-before-last-author-but-leave-it-if-there-are-only-two-aut)

```
% Basic settings 
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
    

% Bibliography management
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
    
% Snippet for removing the last "and" in the case of multiple authors.

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} % order of surname and first name in the bibliography

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{%
    \printdelim{multinamedelim}}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum (\cite{example}).
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Bibliography}]
\end{document}
```

And for the entry I used:

```
@book{example,
author = {P. {DAL ZOTTO} and J. M. {LARRE}  and A. {MERLET} and L. {PICAU} },
title = {Memotech Génie énergétique},
publisher = {Editor Casteilla, France, pages 153 to 159},
year = {2014}
}
```

The output looked like this:

[image: Output]

Comment: Note: `style=authortitle` uses `location` and `pages` also for `@book` (but the formatting with `style=authortitle` is indeed different, so a different style or a modification would be needed).

Comment: `@books` *do* have a field for the publisher address. It's called `location`. If you use `address` in your `.bib` file it will automatically be remapped to `location`. If you want to change the output formatting of that field on the `biblatex` side you need to use `location` (and not `address` as that field is remapped automatically).

Comment: I see! I always wondered why no errors were thrown when entering the address property, but since in most cases it was not a requirement, I never looked deeply into it. Also, since you mentioned this, what do you usually reference in order to check the properties that can be assigned to each entry type?

Comment: For `biblatex` the first thing to look at is the documentation (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf): It lists all types and fields defined in the standard data model (the data model used by all standard styles and in most contributed styles - though contributed styles may change some things) in §2 *Database Guide*.